# Where to declare GUI elements?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have seen two main approaches:

1. Declaring elements as private fields of application frame class. Used by many experienced programmers, but it seems unclean to me because of lots of private fields.
2. Declaring elements as local variables in the constructor right before they used.

What approach is 'better'?

Or the middle of them: declare in constructor, but if the variable is need to be accessed from outside, declare as private field?

Comment: As local variables in the ctor prevents you from accessing them later again easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the books that I've read, a worthwhile goal is to: reduce the visibility and exposure of a variable as much as possible. A good approach is to start by declaring your variable right next to the code that needs it, and then suitably bringing the declaration out of that scope, only as needed.